# Can't run uploadify for asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, uploadify

I have downloaded the example code/demo from:

http://www.technowise.in/2009/12/uploadify-aspnet-c-vb-examples-demo.html

and when I try to run any of the aspx files, I just get the following message from the server:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error: 


Line 46:             ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
Line 47:         -->
Line 48:        <authentication mode="Windows"/>
Line 49:        <!--
Line 50:             The <customErrors> section enables configuration 

Source File: C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\test_uploader\uploadify\web.config    Line: 48 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3623; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.3618
```

Anyone know why this is happening?  I can normally run asp.net 2.0 and above web-forms perfectly will on this server.

Comment: The directory where you are uploading file is it a Virtual Direcotry? `This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.` Secondly does IIS_User has read\write access on the folder and files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because you have place a web.config in a subdirectory and this contains sessions that should be there, except if you define a new application/pool asp.net in this subdirectory of your iis.

From you question, here is the path of your web.config, but this must be one directory up, or not exist at all, or remove the lines that can not be there.

```
C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\test_uploader\uploadify\web.config
```